# burning down a building, curse of strahd

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

So my players went into

> the coffin maker's shop woefully under prepared, woke up the vampire nest

and by the grace of me managed to escape with their lives. But now instead of going out and doing something else they have decided *"you know what, let's just burn it down"*.

I can't think of a reasonable way to say no. I don't really want to either. I just don't know how to go about it.

Do I kill the vampires with the fire? Deal them damage over time? Roll % for falling debris? What about the surrounding buildings? Is there a chance other building will catch fire? The whole town possibly?

Comment: The "let's burn the place" thing happens quite a lot in horror genre games, and often makes sense both out-of-character and in-character in terms of optimising an encounter against tough enemies. I'm interested to see answers that resolve things without rail-roading or destroying the genre tropes - I think that is a difficult path to tread.